# How to run an existing aws amplify project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have been asked to work on an existing `aws amplify` `reactJs` project. Normally I would simply clone the project repo from either github or bitbucket, but this project is am amplify project and requires a whole set of configuration. I have several aws profiles set-up on the cli, and have access to the aws cludservices for this project, but cannot run the app locally because my `aws-exports.js` file does not have the required auhtentication configurations in it.

According to the [amplify cli docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-cli-adds-scaffolding-support-for-amplify-apps-and-authoring-plugins/) for an existing project, I should just be able to run `amplify init --app https://bitbucket.org/brooklynva/brooklyn-ocr-poc.git`. However this tried, and thankfully failed, to update the cloudformation stack on aws. It updated the `aws-exports.js` file but only with this:

```
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "us-east-2"
};


export default awsmobile;
```

So I then found that running `amplify pull --frontend` with some other parameters which I put into a bash file would be the equivalent of running `git pull`. After running that command, still nothing was updated in the config file.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
IFS='|'

REACTCONFIG="{\
\"SourceDir\":\"src\",\
\"DistributionDir\":\"build\",\
\"BuildCommand\":\"npm run-script build\",\
\"StartCommand\":\"npm run-script start\"\
}"
FRONTEND="{\
\"frontend\":\"javascript\",\
\"framework\":\"react\",\
\"config\":$REACTCONFIG\
}"

amplify pull \
--frontend $FRONTEND \
--yes
```

So my question remains, how do I start an already existing `aws amplify` app from an existing project and generate the configuration file necessary to run the app locally without having the person who created the app, share that config file with me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create or use an existing Amplify environment

Check the environments you have available

`amplify env list`

Similar to git, it will show the list of environments (think about this as branches on git)

Check out one of the existing environment or create a new one for you, Amplify allows you to create an environment, for example, for a specific user, i.e: `dev-myuser`

`amplify env checkout <exising-environment>`

or

`amplify env add`

The `add` command is interactive and will ask you a few questions to set up your environment

After that, you should have your `aws-exports.js` set

Then you push your changes

`amplify push`

More details about Amplify environments:
https://read.acloud.guru/multiple-serverless-environments-with-aws-amplify-344759e1be08

From the official documentation: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart#environments-and-teams

Comment: I tried checking out an existing env and still the config file was not updated. I couldn't however checkout the dev env

Comment: I can create a new env. No error happens, but now I manually need to add things like oauth?

Comment: @hyprstack no, you just push the changes and it is gonna create the stack

Answer (score 13):

For me what worked was using the `amplify init` command passing appId instead of the repo url. E.g. `amplify init --appId YOUR_APP_ID`

Comment: The exact cli command is provided in your Amplify console. Log in to your Amplify console, then select the app you want to pull down. On the app screen is an expand button that will give you the command to copy and paste.

Answer (score 4):

In my case flow for this was:

1. `git clone (link to project)`
2. `yarn` (or `npm i`)
3. `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`
4. `amplify configure`
5. `amplify pull --appId (your app id) --envName (env name)`
6. `yarn start` / `npm run start`

   Docs for **3,4** - https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/start/install/#option-2-follow-the-instructions
   Command for **5** can be copied from amplify console

Comment: amplify pull --appId (your app id) --envName (env name) worked for me after I erased amplify directory for a fresh pull

Comment: @Dylanw There is a nuance with erasing, because we can configure amplify in at least two ways: through the AWS Console and through configuration files.
In the case of working through the console - everything is ok. In the case of working with config files, they are stored in the repository in the amplify folder and change / add settings in the AWS Console with each build. Therefore, deleting the amplify folder may reset important project settings.
Example: loss of read/write permissions for custom fields added through Cognito Console and specified in cli-inputs.json manually.